# C ++ std::map with custom comparer for keeping tournament of matches

Tags: c++, stdmap

I would like to save results of tournament in some container. For every match I need to store names of players and a number of points. For example:

```
map["player1:player2"] = {2,4};
```

I want to retrieve from this container not only by key `"player1:player2"`, but even by the inverse key `"player2:player1"` and I would like to get the inverse results.

I am about to use `std::map` and make some smart wrapper around it. Maybe there is some trick using custom comparer, custom retrieve and save functions.

Is `std::map` a good choice for this or is something else better?

EDIT:

I summarized these comments into solution which looks like this:

```
struct Match
{
    std::string player1;
    std::string player2;

    int pointsPlayer1;
    int pointsPlayer2;

    std::string getKey()
    {
        return player1 + ":" + player2;
    }

    Match reverse()
    {
        Match reversed;
        reversed.player1 = player2;
        reversed.player2 = player1;
        reversed.pointsPlayer1 = pointsPlayer2;
        reversed.pointsPlayer2 = pointsPlayer1;
        return reversed;
    }
};

class Tournament
{   
    std::map<std::string, Match> _games;
public: 
    void insert(Match match);
};

void Tournament::insert(Match match)
{
    _games.insert({ match.getKey(), match });
    Match reversed = match.reverse();
    _games.insert({ reversed.getKey(), reversed });
}
```

I choose more simple approach and I don't mind that every results is there twice, because insert function replaces both matched every time and encapsulation can guarantee this (it does not expose pointer, just struct).

Comment: Another idea would be to use a `std::map<std::set<std::string>, ...>` that way your key would be `set(("player1", "player2"))` which would be equivalent.  You could also make your own custom class which implements `operator<` that has set semantics and use that as the key

Comment: If matches involve only two players, you're better off with a std::pair of strings than a std::set.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement it.

Comment: @Dalzhim the problem with `pair<>` is `make_pair("foo", "bar") != make_pair("bar", "foo")` so some care will be needed when interacting with the map

Comment: @AnthonySottile `std::set` messes up the order of the players which is important in this case since they are coupled to a score.

Comment: yes, @Heike is right. sets have automatic duplicate filtering and sorting, that will mess up the things. So my suggestion is to use a std::vector with std::map. `std::map<std::vector<std::string>, ...>` and then write caomarator accordingly

Comment: you should use a comparator function to map, input args will be std::vectors.

Comment: maybe like this http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecab474133d8a728

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, using a `std::map` can't work. The simple reason is that you want to insert `map["player1:player2"] = {2, 4};` into it, but from then on you need it to return `{4, 2}` when you ask it for `map["player2:player1"]`. So, not only do you need different keys to reference the same data (which `std::map` can give you with a custom comparator), but you also need the same data in different format depending on the order in the keys, which `std::map` can't do.

Now, how to solve this? Firstly, think about the interface that you need. At the moment, you have functions to insert and query tournament results. My crystal ball also tells me you will want to iterate over all results in the tournament, query whether a match already took place and perhaps reset the content of the table. So, go and write down the interfaces to those functions first and document their behaviour, especially for cornercases.

Then, think about how to implement that. The most straightforward way is probably to use a `map<pair<string,string>, pair<int,int>>` to store the scores. Now, when inserting, you either store the results redundantly (i.e. store both the score for "player1:player2" and "player2:player1") which would then give the proper results on retrieval with either variant. Alternatively, normalize the order (sort the players lexicographically) and on retrieval, optionally invert the order of both the key before lookup and the results afterwards to get the right order.

Notes:

- There is an alternative approach: If you map how many points player X scored against player Y, you have the same information. The according data structure is `map<string, map<string, int>>`. To insert a match result, you just do `res["player1"]["player2"] = 2;` and `res["player2"]["player1"] = 4;`. I wouldn't do that, except maybe as implementation behind above described interface.
- I prefer a pair over the string "player1:player2" even if I usually had to display it like the string. The simple reason is that it doesn't mix up representation with the data, which gives you cleaner code. For the same reason, I wouldn't for example store e.g. 3% as a string or as integer value 3, but rather as floating point value 0.03, as it lends itself to according calculations much better (leaving aside floating point inaccuracy issues).

Comment: That sounds good. I like the idea pair as key, I will change it.I may try double dictionary (or how you call it) as well.

Comment: The best approach is probably an `unordered_map`: player => int plus a (possibly sparse) matrix with the match results.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would help:

```
#include <map>
#include <array>
#include <string>

class Player {
private:
    std::string m_strName;
    unsigned m_uScore;

public:
    Player() : m_uScore( 0 ) {}
    explicit Player( const std::string& strName, unsigned score = 0 ) :
        m_strName( strName ),
        m_uScore( score )
    {}

    const std::string& getName() const {
        return m_strName;
    }

    const unsigned getScore() const {
        return m_uScore;
    }

    void setName( const std::string& strName ) {
        m_strName = strName;
    }

    void setScore( const unsigned& uScore ) {
        m_uScore = uScore;
    }

    bool operator==( const Player& p ) const {
        if ( m_uScorescore == p.m_uScore && m_strName == p.strName ) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool operator!=( const Player& p ) const {
        return !operator==( p );
    }

    bool operator<( const Player& p ) const {
         return m_uScore < p.m_uScore;
    }

    bool operator> ( const Player& p ) const {
         return m_uScore > p.m_uScore;
    }

    const Player& lessThan( const Player& p ) const {
          return m_uScore < p.m_uScore ? *this : p;
    }

    const Player& greaterThan( const Player& p ) const {
          return m_uScore > p.m_uScore ? *this : p;
    }
}; // Player

int main() {
    unsigned uMatch = 1;
    // Since you need to compare 2 for each match I did this but isn't necessary 
    // You can choose which ever method is necessary. But since this
    // Has only 2 of the same type of object then this made sense to me.
    // I Initialized the std::array with the first results it isn't needed 
    // but used to show how 2 players are grouped to one entity but yet
    // remaining individual objects.
    std::array<Player,2> aPlayerResults = { Player( "Player1", 20 ),
                                            Player( "Player2", 10 ) };

    // This map then would hold every game-round( match results )
    std::map<unsigned, std::array<Player,2>> mMatches;
    mMatches[uMatch] = aPlayerResults;

    // Now Just Update The Values
    uMatch = 2;
    aPlayerResults.at(0).setName( std::string( "Player3" ) );
    aPlayerResults.at(0).setScore( 19 );
    aPlayerResults.at(1).setName( std::string( "Player4" ) );
    aPlayerResults.at(1).setScore( 17 );

    // Add To Map
    mMatches[uMatch] = aPlayerResults;        


    return 0;
}
```

As you can see with player being a class object associating a player name with a score and keeping the data private you can use accessory functions to set and get values, there is a default constructor to create an empty player object to fill out later, plus an explicit constructor that excepts at least an std string for a name, and score is option. If score is left blank then you have a player that exists before any match and once the match is over you can then use the setScore method. There are operators to test if Player1 == Player2 or !=, and < & > operators that return true or false for if statements. And if you want to compare two Players and return one player or the other based on if the score is > or < there are two functions that do this for you. All the tools are in this nice little class, and you can even expand it.

I used the std::array since we know that there will only be 2 players against each other per match such as in a game of chess. Now if you need more players you could either increase the number of array elements, as long as the value is small say less then 10 or 20 at max, if there are more players then this, you will want to switch the std::array to a std::vector of Player objects or std::vector of Player object pointers pending on your needs. The map just associates an unsigned as the key or index with either the std::array or std::vector of players. The index in the map makes it nice since each match or game is unique and normal maps won't allow duplicate keys. Also using the unsigned makes the map's [] notation of assignment much nicer to read.

Of course you can always create a function that would take in either 2 Players by constant Reference or 2 Player pointers and they would set these players into the map for you.

You can also prepopulate your map with a bunch of player objects that all have unique names with no scores then later on after each match is finished you can go through a for loop using an iterator to update all the score values, then create another function to go through your entire map to sort each match by greatest value first or second etc. This is just a guideline of how something like you stated can be achieved. There is never an exact "Correct Way" for there are many ways to achieve the same desired results when writing a program.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a simple function for this work:

```
string getResult(map<string, string> scores, string key) {
    vecor<string> splited = split(key, ":");
    if (scores.containsKey(key))
        return scores.get(key);
    else
        return scored.get(splited[1] + ":" + splited[0]);
}
```